# Java bit operation to remove (zero out) un-interested bits

Tags: java, bit-shift

Example

```
byte b = 127;
```

(initialize be to equal 11111111)

Now I only care about bits 1 and 0

how do i bit shift do get 00000011

I think this is called "masking bits" if I'm right?

I tried 
b << 5 
then 
b>> 5 
to zero out the other bits but that's just wrong

My goal

```
switch ((myByte >> 3) & 3)
{
    case 3:
        resevered = true;
        break;
    case 2:
        open = true;
        break;
    case 1:
        SingleOnly = true;
        break;
    case 0:
        daulMode = true;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
b & 0x03
```

will give you a byte containing the first two bits, with the remaining bits zero-filled.

This works because 0x03 is `00000011` in binary, and

```
11111111
```

AND

```
00000011
```

zeroes the first six bits, leaving only the remaining two bits.